# Call using Intent in android

Tags: java, android

This is my code. I don't know why its not working.

```
package com.example.designing;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Informationpage extends ActionBarActivity {
private static Button callbutton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_informationpage);
        callbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       callbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String number = "01238888397";
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse( "tel" + number));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.informationpage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have also included the required  in my manifest file.. which is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.designing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>   

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Listviewactivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_listviewactivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Informationpage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_informationpage" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Whenever i run this application it stops. It is linked with another file which has a button. When i click on a button, this activity is called and the application stops. Please help!

Comment: are you getting error??

Comment: @khan did you get your answer or you still facing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
String url = "tel:3334444";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
```

instead of this:

```
                String number = "01238888397";
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse( "tel" + number));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace below line

```
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse( "tel" + number));
```

with

```
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse( "tel:" + number));
```

Add column(:) after `tel`

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" +your number));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

@khan please check this tutorial

```
 private void call() {
      Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("01238888397"));
      try{
         startActivity(in);
      }

      catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourActivity is not founded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
```

Android - Phone Calls

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_phone_calls.htm